# the command "npm" returns with an error

Tags: node.js

*

> C:\Users\xxxxx>npm
>   module.js:471
>      throw err;
>      ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
>    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
>   at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>   at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>      at Object. >(C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\unsupported.js:2:>14)
>      at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>      at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>
> C:\Users\xxxxx>

Comment: Do you have a question? Please read [ask].

Comment: typo `semver` ?

Comment: what exactly you had tried to run, please share the command

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that it cannot find the module `semver`.

Try running `npm install semver --save`

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm install semver --save` in your console under current directory where you are starting the node app.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install semver --save
```

works.